# SharePoint 2010/2013 Upgrade and License Type

Tags: 2010, 2013, upgrade, licensing

I am working on a test upgrade of SharePoint 2010 to 2013 on VMware in a dev/test environment. It's a two server farm with publishing template for Intranet, standard license.

I was just about to migrate the databases when I noticed in 2013 Central Admin that Enterprise license seems to be enabled out of the box (radio button checked but greyed out). However, when I run `(Get-SPFarm).UserLicensingEnabled`, it comes back as false.

My question is: what do I need to do in the 2013 version to ensure that attaching the 2010 content database does not generate some kind of error relating to a possible conflict in licensing type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the server is running Enterprise, you'll have no 'conflict'.  UserLicensingEnabled = false just means that you have not enabled the licensing separation -- in other words, all users must have a Standard + Enterprise CAL for this particular farm (versus enabling user licensing and assigning them to a Standard-only license).  MSDN only has Enterprise, you may be able to find a Standard ISO on the VLK site.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. So I just leave it as is in dev, and only enable standard licensing via PowerShell in production?

Comment: I would find the appropriate Standard media for production.  If you install Enterprise in prod, you must have Enterprise CALs for the SharePoint server(s).  Again, look to your VAR or the VLK site.

Comment: Indeed the standard iso is on the volume site :-)